# Captcha implementation

Tags: spring, spring-mvc

Changes
    Create a new API to get the 4-digit captcha

- The API will return an image for captcha
- The image will be having a random 4-Digit captcha
- In the response header there should be an encrypted key

  -- The encrypted key will be having 4-digit captcha with a secret key

https://sourceforge.net/projects/skewpassim/ - this link has servlet code - PassImage - code for generating captcha can some one please help in translating code to spring controller

```
@RequestMapping(value="/captchaforgotpassword", method=RequestMethod.GET,  produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
        public ResponseEntity getCaptchakey(HttpServletRequest request) throws Exception {
          ResponseEntity response1 = null;
         BufferedImage imageData = passImage.generateImg(request);
              return ResponseEntity.ok(imageData) ;
             }
```

I am trying to hit the url from postman , it is showing 500 internal server error and got below exception

> Root cause of ServletException.
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error
>   creating bean with name 'loginController': Injection of autowired
>   dependencies failed; nested exception is
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not
>   autowire field: private xxxxxxx.service.PassImage
>   xxxxxx.controller.LoginController.passImage; nested exception is
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error
>   creating bean with name 'passImage' defined in file
>   [D:xxxxxx\commons\service\PassImage.class]: Instantiation of bean
>   failed; nested exception is java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not
>   initialize class com.lifung.commons.service.PassImage

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please provide a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example. **Show us the code for your latest attempt** and where you got stuck. and explain why the result is not what you expected.  Edit your question to include the code, please don't add it in a comment, as it will probably be unreadable.
https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

It is better to show what is actually happening, rather than describing what you expect to happen.

Comment: I have added the code and exception.Please check